# Why do AUR Web, and deployment options appear different?

Tags: linux, intellij-idea, archlinux

According to https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/, the current IntelliJ Ultimate Edition version in AUR is intellij-idea-ultimate-edition 15.0.2-1 which I would like to install. However, when requesting installation, it provides intellij-idea-ue-eap-16.0.0.144.2925.2-1:

```
yaourt -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition

Resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) intellij-idea-ue-eap-16.0.0.144.2925.2-1

Total Installed Size:  876.70 MiB
```

Why is there a mismatch between the web and distribution versions of this package?

How can I install the non EAP version 15 through package management? The Community edition being non-commercial is available in the office repository, and the version 15 is thus available.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30130934/how-to-install-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu
This might give you the needed info for your problem.

Comment: Cheers, this is my fall back position, but was hoping for a package management solution so future package updates are suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cross posted this issue on the Antergos Forum and received a (currently unavailable) [response](https://forum.antergos.com/topic/3747) yaourt -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition) from a maintainer of the IntelliJ AUR package. The problem lay in the incorrect packaging of the EAP version of Intellij and the maintainer has now resolved this issue. I have since installed IntelliJ v15 using:

`yaourt -S intellij-idea-ultimate-edition`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like [this](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/16/how-to-install-intellij-14-idea-on-arch-linux-easy-guide/)?
Check the link, it is quite easy to use and it is a usefull tutorial.

Comment: I've updated the question title to better reflect my question. I know I can download, extract, and install manually but I was trying to understand how to use AUR to achieve the same goal so easier future system upgrades would be possible.